# Codename One DateSpinner

Tags: codenameone

I created a DateSpinner in my Desktop app,but the spinner is not displaying the month,day or year properly.half of the part was not visible to the user.
Can you please help to resolve the issue?
![DateSpinner Image][![Below link shows how the date spinner visible to the user][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kMmS4.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kMmS4.png)

Answer (score 1):

The `DateSpinner` class has been deprecated for a while. I suggest using the `Picker` component which is better looking overall. See: https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/ui/package-summary.html